# HDFS caching with SparkSQL

Tags: caching, apache-spark-sql, hive, hdfs

## env

- spark 3.1.2
- hive 3.1.2
- hadoop 3.2.1

## problem

- spark sql with hive metastore connection
- for example, make table A with hdfs caching data in memory.
- and make table B with non-hdfs caching data in hdfs.( but data content is same. )

I executed same query with table A and B.
I expected A table's query execution time must be faster than B table's query, but it didn't.
Actually query execution time between A and B table was almost same.

Is there anything to do enable HDFS caching with SparkSQL using hive metastore?

## example code

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as Fd
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

spark_executor_cores = 8
spark_executor_memory = '3g'
spark_instances = 50
spark_shuffle_partitions = 1000
spark_default_parallelism = 1000

conf = SparkConf()

conf.setAppName("test application")
conf.set('spark.yarn.queue', 'default')
conf.set('spark.executor.memory', str(spark_executor_memory))
conf.set('spark.executor.instances', str(spark_instances))
conf.set('spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold', spark_instances * int(spark_executor_cores))

conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", str(spark_shuffle_partitions))
conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", str(spark_default_parallelism))
conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.enabled', 'true')
conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled', 'true')
conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.localShuffleReader.enabled', 'true')
conf.set('spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled', 'true') 
conf.set('spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled', 'true')
conf.set('spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled', 'true')

conf.set('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', metastore_dir)
conf.set('spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL', metastore_url)
ss = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = ss

sql = spark.sql
```

```sql
# example query
# partition = hour, logtype

sql("""
SELECT <columns>,
...
...
FROM <table name>
WHERE hour = <hour>
AND logtype = <logtype>
group by logtype
""").show()
```

Comment: please add example codes